# Как иправить ошибку UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in invalid start byte

Tags: python, pandas, csv, unicode, decode

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
fig=None
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data/2020_ready.csv',encoding='utf-8', index_col='date', parse_dates=['date'])#, 
import bar_chart_race as bcr
#df = bcr.load_dataset('data/videogame', index_col='date')
bcr.bar_chart_race(
    df=df,
    filename='test1.mp4',
    orientation='h',
    sort='desc',
    n_bars=30,
    fixed_order=False,
    fixed_max=False,
    steps_per_period=20,
    interpolate_period=False,
    label_bars=True,
    bar_size=.95,
    period_label={'x': .99, 'y': .20, 'ha': 'right', 'va': 'center', 'size': 20},
    period_fmt='%B %Y',
    period_summary_func=lambda v, r: {'x': .99, 'y': .10,
                                      's': f'Top 10 views: {v.nlargest(10).sum():,.0f}',
                                      'ha': 'right', 'size': 10, 'family': 'Tahoma'},
    #perpendicular_bar_func='median',
    period_length=1000,
    figsize=(8, 4.5),
    dpi=240,
    cmap='dark24',
    title='Most popular',
    title_size='',
    bar_label_size=7,
    tick_label_size=7,
    shared_fontdict={'family' : 'Tahoma', 'color' : '.1'},
    scale='linear',
    writer=None,
    fig=fig,
    bar_kwargs={'alpha': .7},
    filter_column_colors=True)  

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

> [image: Цитата]
>
> эти данные вставить в эксель

```
data    50 Cent Aaliyah Aaron Carter    Aaron Paul  Adam Driver Adam Levine
01.07.2015  10043   6454    1943    5691    2562    8765
02.07.2015  9722    7383    1853    5319    2458    8497
03.07.2015  8880    6298    1764    5271    3737    8940
04.07.2015  11003   6113    1657    5425    3017    9703
05.07.2015  11166   6091    1835    6724    3172    9920
06.07.2015  20089   5838    1800    6088    3343    8358
07.07.2015  14031   6357    1794    5771    2807    9752
08.07.2015  11580   6580    1805    6432    2715    7835
09.07.2015  10300   6680    1867    5943    2277    10472
10.07.2015  12415   7575    1678    6059    2448    8778
11.07.2015  10415   8769    1742    6538    8342    9998
12.07.2015  11614   7054    1876    7188    7343    9853
13.07.2015  46312   6437    1792    6761    6171    8756
14.07.2015  47444   5812    1886    5827    4744    10374
```

При таком большом количестве данных выписывает ошибку. Как эту ошибку проигнорировать или исправить?

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\!!!1\1prog\rantings\2.py", line 21, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv('data/2020rating.csv',encoding='utf-8', index_col='data', parse_dates=['data'])#,
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 448, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 880, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1114, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1891, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 529, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 720, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 916, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 2063, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4492: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Возможно у вас файл csv не в кодировке utf-8, а например в cp1251, и где-то в середине встречается какой-то русский текст.

Comment: @insolor кодировка 65001 utf-8 без BOM

Comment: И как вы это определили?

Comment: зашла в блокнот через akelpad, там внизу написано эта информация. Если другая кодировка то пишется что-то другое

Comment: Akelpad (как и другие текстовые редакторы) при открытии пытается угадать кодировку, то что он пишет внизу - еще ничего не значит.

Comment: Просто попробуйте заменить в коде `encoding='utf-8'` на `encoding='cp1251'`